# how to run main method class using java 11

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I have one Test.java source code file

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("works);
   }
}
```

> ```
> java Test.java
> ```

It works fine. If `Test.java` source code file has two classes like `Test` and `Test1`

```
class Test {
    public static void m1(){
        System.out.println(" m1 ");
    }
}

class Test1 {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(" works ");
    }
}
```

> ```
> java Test.java
> ```

It threw an exception that

> error: can't find main(String[]) method in class: Test

So, is there any way to compile and run java program directly which has two classes?

Comment: Java source files should not contain two classes (at least not two top level classes).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Interestingly, the [single file source code launch JEP](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330) reads in the compilation mode, *The source file should contain one or more top-level classes, the first of which is taken as the class to be executed.*

Comment: @Ghanshyam But the same JEP also reads, *It is an error if there is a class on the application classpath whose name is the same as that of the class to be executed.* Possibly that's the case your test is falling into since you're executing `Test.java` which is not a top-level class. But the question remains on how to execute `Test1` here. Another note from the same doc about execution, *The class to be executed is the first top-level class found in the source file. It must contain a declaration of the standard public static void main(String[]) method.*. Q: Is there a way to specify this class?

Comment: The `main()` should be included in the class that has the same name of the file.

Comment: @ElliotFrisch I really don't see the point of package visible two line mapstruct mapper or Lombok data class definitions that are only used in a single service to be declared in a separate file.

Comment: @Ghanshyam checkpoint last point in my post <b> Multiple Classes in a Single File <b>

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch places of your class definitions:

```java
class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Test1.m1();
        System.out.println("works");
   }
}
class Test1 {
    public static void m1(){
        System.out.println(" m1 ");
    }
}
```

In that way your code will work.

As you see in the example you can call `Test1.m1()` from your main method and you can see the output.

Answer (score 0):

I tried and it worked
If there are multiple classes in a single source code file then we need to put class at the beginning of source file which contains the main(String args[]) method.

Comment: Can confirm, it works that way. The class with the `main` regardless of what its name is, should be the first class of the source file to make this work. But would have been much better if I could have possible specified a class name explicitly. Wouldn't it?

Comment: @Naman the goal of this feature is to allow `.java` classes to run like script files. Needing another parameter argument to work, like a class name, would contradict that goal. Properly configured, I can run `.java` files via double-click in my desktop. Needing a class name would not be helpful then.

Comment: @Holger *Needing another parameter argument to work, like a class name, would contradict that goal* It could, I agree. *Properly configured, I can run .java files via double-click in my desktop.* I am not sure of the configurations here, but I would assume those could be tweaked with an additional parameter as well. Yes, all of this eventually would contradict the goal. But a bit too strange that running a source file as `java Test.java`, executes a `Test1` class within that file and that is dependent on the order of the classes placed in the file.

Comment: @Naman I configured the double-click behavior only once, for every `.java` file. Adding a class name that could be different for every file would not work. Well, the decision to run the first class rather than the class with a matching name (which is the only top level class that could be `public`), could be discussed. But the more important point is to have a consistent rule. And, well, in java files, intended to act like a script, my `main` method would be the first thing in the first class anyway, so I see it immediately when opening the file in a text editor.